# Does Java 8 Streaming Filter & Collect return references to same objects in the list?

Tags: java, reference, java-stream

For example consider the code below

```
List<Reference> references = context.getReferences()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(ref -> ref.getCondition() == SOMETHING_DESIRABLE)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now if I mutate each reference inside `references` list, will it be reflected inside the original `context.references`?

Comment: What do you mean by _mutate each reference_? Do you mean replacing a (reference) value in the list? `reference.set(0, new Reference(..))`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mean to say change it or cause one or many of its internal member variable values to change.

Comment: Ok, so not _mutating the reference_. You meant mutating the objects being referencing by the reference values in the list? Yes, such changes would be reflected in the original `context.getReferences()` collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no general way to clone objects in Java.

It would be *fundamentally impossible* for it to automatically return different instances.

Comment: @SLacks It makes sense. But I am not understanding what prevents the streaming/collect from cloning/deep copying the objects first and returning a completely new reference?

Comment: @Ace Why would one like to do that?

Comment: @Ace you can use a map function in combination with your own 'clone' implementation. E.g. `stream.map(Reference::clone).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo The answer here by SLaks stated that it is fundamentally impossible to return different instances. I was referring to that statement.

Comment: @Ace: I mean for the stream to _automatically_ copy things, without you telling it how.  Obviously, you can pass any callback you want.

Comment: There is no general way to deep clone objects.

Comment: Indeed, there are Objects that cannot be copied at all (e.g. Singletons).

Comment: Why don't you try to use Object Mapper, map each object to the same class and voila!

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is yes. As depicted below:

```
  private void run() {

    List<Ref> original = new ArrayList<>();
    original.add(new Ref(1, "A"));
    original.add(new Ref(2, "B"));
    original.add(new Ref(3, "C"));

    System.out.println("Original: " + original);
    // Original: [Ref{id=1, name='A'}, Ref{id=2, name='B'}, Ref{id=3, name='C'}]

    List<Ref> results = original.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("Aggregated: " + results);
    // Aggregated: [Ref{id=1, name='A'}, Ref{id=2, name='B'}, Ref{id=3, name='C'}]

    results.forEach(r -> r.name = r.name + "CHANGED");

    System.out.println("Original: " + original);
    //Original: [Ref{id=1, name='ACHANGED'}, Ref{id=2, name='BCHANGED'}, Ref{id=3, name='CCHANGED'}]

  }
```